# Recipe Finder with PHP and MySQL based on Ingredients

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a cooking recipe-website and i want to create a recipe finder based on the used incredients.

My current finder only works with 3 ingredients right.

The Finder should return the right recipe(s) based on the used incredients (should work with 1-n*)

My Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `INGREDIENTS` (
  `ingredients_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ingredients_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `INGREDIENTS_POS` (
  `ingredients_pos_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ingredients_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredients_unit` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ingredients_pos_id`),
  KEY `ingredients_detail_fk` (`ingredients_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RECIPES` (
  `recipes_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(2000) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `count_persons` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `accepted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipes_id`),
  KEY `recipes_user_fk` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=88 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RECIPES_POS` (
  `recipes_pos_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `recipes_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredients_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ingredients_value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`recipes_pos_id`),
  KEY `recipe_pos_rec_id` (`recipes_id`),
  KEY `recipes_pos_ingredient_fk` (`ingredients_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=58 ;
```

My buggy Solution (doesn't support count from 1-n):

```
<?php
include 'db_connect.php';

$q = urldecode(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']));
$parameter = explode ('$',$q);
$var = 0;
//print_r($parameter);

foreach($parameter as $ing)
{
    //echo $ing;
    $sql = "SELECT ingredients_id FROM  INGREDIENTS WHERE name='".$ing."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or exit('{"Data":null,"Message":null,"Code":500}');
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $arr_id[$var] = $row['ingredients_id'];
    $var++;

}
//print_r($arr_id);

$sql = "SELECT r.recipes_id FROM RECIPES r, RECIPES_POS rp WHERE r.recipes_id = rp.recipes_id ";

foreach($arr_id as $id)
{
$sql .= "AND rp.ingredients_id =".$id . " ";
}
//echo $sql;
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db) or exit('{"Data":null,"Message":null,"Code":500}');
mysql_close($db);
$rec;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
             {
                 //echo "test";
                 $_GET['id'] = $row['recipes_id'];
                 $rec= include('get_recipe_byID.php');

             }

//print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
if (count($arr_id) == 0)
    {
        echo '{"Data":null,"Message":null,"Code":404}';
        die();
    }

?>
```

I need a better solution for that chase.
Maybe SQL itself will help me to find the right recipes

thx

Comment: Please define "better" - and if you ask a question, you might get some help here with an answer.

Comment: what is ``n`` here? Is the star used as in mathematics?

Comment: Do you know about the ``JOIN`` SQL clause? I think you might be able to do away with your first query and instead ``JOIN`` that table in.

Comment: Generally, when you have a ``SELECT`` and you iterate all the results and put them in a second ``SELECT`` query, you're probably doing some kind of ``JOIN`` like functionality. Let SQL handle (i.e. filter) your data like it is supposed to.

Comment: and ``1-n*`` is the number of used ingredients or what?

Comment: i am not the (my)sql expert, can you please post an answer?

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection. Use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php on your ``$ing`` when inserting it in your SQL statement. Alternatively, use prepared statements.

Comment: ok sorry: my php method gets the name of the ingredients with the $_GET parameter. I parse it into a array and make my query by adding the ids. The method should work with 1 submited ingredients and morn (2,3,4,...*)

Comment: 1. quickly learn mysql, then see these solutions: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html Replace tags with ingredient, and you can have some flexible queries (AND, OR, etc)

Comment: What do you mean by answer? I've given you lots of tips now. You can fix your own problems based on the help I've given you. Wikipedia has information on JOIN's.

Comment: You're using ``include`` wrong. See ``Example #4 Comparing return value of include`` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded. Using urldecode() on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST could have unexpected and dangerous results. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: whats wrong with include

Comment: @user547995: see the example. The opening brace needs to come before the ``include`` keyword. It is not a regular function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That query helped me a lot:

```
   select r.recipes_id
    from RECIPES r
    inner join RECIPES_POS rp on r.recipes_id = rp.recipes_id
    where rp.ingredients_id in (4, 6)
    group by r.recipes_id
    having count(distinct rp.ingredients_id) = 2
```